# A java class method can call another java class method. Then why do you need RequestDispatcher?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, requestdispatcher

Servlets are java classes. A java class method can call another java class method. Then why do you need RequestDispatcher?

Comment: A `RequestDispatcher` has access to and involves the entire Servlet stack provided by your container. You don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a request dispatcher you specify the resource to include or forward to as a URI so you can dispatch to resources other than java classes, for example a static file, a jsp, a jsf page, or another servlet which your java class does not have access to.

Also the dispatcher enforces rules such as an included resource cannot set a header and the response is completed on return from forward.

If you don't need these rules enforced and you only call well behaved available java classes then I agree you don't need to use a request dispatcher.